# Expect script fails when running from crontab but works when run manually

Tags: linux, shell, cron, expect, scp

When I run this shell script with the crontab it doesn't work
but if I do it manually if it works.

I am missing an environment variable to configure or something additional needs to be done to make it work.

Thanks for your help.

Script: /process/files/test_expect_cron.sh

```
remoteuser="user"
remotehost="10.77.88.111"
remotepass="pass1"

cd /process/files
pathfiles="/process/files"
remote_files="/data/20201129/*FILES_20201129*"

cat > expect.dat << EOF
    spawn scp -r $remoteuser@$remotehost:$remote_files $pathfiles/.
    expect "*?assword*"
    send "$remotepass\r"
    interact
EOF
expect "expect.dat"
```

Crontab

```
40      11      *       *       * sh /process/files/test_expect_cron.sh
```

Comment: Is the cron user allowed to write files in /process/files? Does the /process/files/expect.dat file contain what you think it should? Is scp in the PATH of the cron environment? Is expect in that PATH? See also https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cron/info

Comment: I'm running into this exact issue

Comment: @JoeBanks The solution I found was to change 
```
interact
```

to

```
expect eof
    
exit
```

If anyone has a better solution, post it

Comment: @Tomas : What point is it to use `interact` in a script, which is run in the background and has nobody it could possibly interact with?

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found was to change

```
interact
```

to

```
expect eof 
exit
```

If anyone has a better solution, post it